# Apache Tika do not extract first line of the RTF file, It only extract last three char of first line.

Tags: apache-tika

**I have added the RTF file in comment.Copy the following text in text editor and save as RTF format.**

[image: This is a view of RFT file when you will open in any RTF viewer.]

```
BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(new File("level1Missing.rtf"));
ParseContext pcontext = new ParseContext();
RTFParser rt = new RTFParser();
rt.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata, pcontext);
//getting the content of the document
System.out.println("Contents of the PDF :\n\n" + handler.toString());
```

[image: Output of the above code is.]

Comment: This is an RTF file.



{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\deff0 {\rtf1\ansi\deff0
{\fonttbl{\f0 Arial;}}\f0
{\line
{\b Level1} : \par}
{\line
This is level1 paragraph\line
This is level1 paragraph\line
This is level1 paragraph\line
This is level1 paragraph\line
This is level1 paragraph\line
This is level1 paragraph\par}
{\line
{\b Level2} : \par}
This is level2 paragraph.\line
This is level2 paragraph.\line
This is level2 paragraph.\par}
} \line  \par}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my view, Apache Tika has no problem. The criticality is in the rtf file; there is a `\par` less before `{\line {\b Level1} : \par}`.

You can try with this another simple file:

```
{\rtf1\ansi{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss Helvetica;}\f0\par
This is some {\b bold} text.\par
}
```

If you remove `\par` before `This is some {\b bold} text.\par`, tika will extract the last chars of the first line.